# How to use sequence of variables (Sequence) correctly?

Tags: list-manipulation, calculus-and-analysis, functions, function-construction

Why does the function `EER[1,2]` have a different value than the function `EERR[1,2]`? Isn't the entry `Kx[x, y]` equivalent to this `Kx[Sequence @@ var]`? How to write `EERR[Sequence @@ varr]` so that it produces the same number as this `EER[x_, y_]`?

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
Kx[x_, y_] := x^2 + y;
var = {x, y};
varr = Pattern[#, Blank[]] & /@ var;
Px[x1_, y1_] := x1^3 - y1;
var1 = {x1, y1};
EER[x_, y_] := Kx[x, y] + Px[x, y];
EER[1, 2]
(*2*)
EERR[Sequence @@ varr] := Kx[Sequence @@ var] + Px[Sequence @@ var];
EERR[1, 2]
(*x^2 + x^3*)
```

Comment: You need to `Evaluate` the RHS of EERR (in the definition).

Comment: @Alan, thanks! Could you please show

Comment: `EERR[Sequence @@ varr] := Evaluate[Kx[Sequence @@ var] + Px[Sequence @@ var]];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One recipe:

```
With[{var = var},
 EERRM[Sequence @@ varr] := (Kx @@ var) + (Px @@ var)
 ]
EERRM[1,2]
```

(* 2 *)

or, as you used

```
With[{var = var}, 
 EERRR[Sequence @@ varr] := 
   Kx[Sequence @@ var] + Px[Sequence @@ var];
 ]

EERRR[1,2]
```

(* 2 *)

Comment: Thank you very much! Сould you please explain this construct why it doesn't work without With (it's not a very obvious structure)

Comment: @MamMam The real problem here is not a sequence (the title therefore is misleading), but localization of variables. Usually in the definition of function one has to have same name for pattern and variable it represents, i.e. f[x_]:=x. But in your case your have f[varr_]:=var, which are different. Therefore your have to "insert" in the definition correct variables. This is most easily to do with With[] construction, which replaces all occurrences of var before evaluating its body.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 2):

Here's your definition for `EERR`:

```
EERR[Sequence @@ varr] := Kx[Sequence @@ var] + Px[Sequence @@ var]
```

How does that get stored as a replacement rule? You can find out by looking at `DownValues`:

```
DownValues[EERR]
```

`{HoldPattern[EERR[x_, y_]] :> Kx[Sequence @@ var] + Px[Sequence @@ var]}`

It held the right-hand side completely unevaluated, but it did evaluate the left-hand side. And notice that `x` and `y` do not show up on the right hand side. So, when it goes to apply this rule, it won't do any replacements. So, it will go on to evaluate the right-hand side as-is.

You can force evaluation:

```
EERR[Sequence @@ varr] := Evaluate[Kx[Sequence @@ var] + Px[Sequence @@ var]]
```

And now...

```
DownValues[EERR]
```

`{HoldPattern[EERR[x_, y_]] :> x^2 + x^3}`